# Get Android owner's full name. Before Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android

I know, It's possible to get owner's Google username and email address on older versions. And it’s possible to get full name on Ice Cream Sandwich. I have to get it on older devices.  Maybe somehow ask Google about full name of email/username owner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `API Level 14` there is provided additional info about user with [`ContactsContract.Profile`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Profile.html). It is not available in previous versions - there is just [`AccountManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) which provides [`Account`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/Account.html) data - only e-mail address with account type.